# How to compile LLVM bitcode to native binary

Tags: ios, llvm, bitcode

Let's suppose I have a binary with __LLVM bitcode section (an iOS app).

Is there a way of recompiling the platform-specific code from the bitcode?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. You can do Archive in Xcode  and then export function. Then there is option "recompile from bitcode".

This uses /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/bitcode_build_tool to recompile the app.